# cannot connect to another email server to send email

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, exim, outboundrules

My GCP server is running OK for more than 500 days, but after reboot, my server cannot connect to another smtp server to send out emails.

```
[root@instance-02 ]# !1010
tail -1000 /var/log/exim/mainlog|grep smart
2020-11-10 10:32:09 1kcJQ1-0003zu-Oo == root@instance-02.asia-east1-b.c.acoustic-cirrus-222102.internal R=smart_route T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2020-11-10 10:33:09 1kcJR0-00040w-1g == root@instance-02.asia-east1-b.c.acoustic-cirrus-222102.internal R=smart_route T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2020-11-10 10:34:08 1kcJRx-00041i-Eq == root@instance-02.asia-east1-b.c.acoustic-cirrus-222102.internal R=smart_route T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
```

It seems related to outbound traffic.

How to solve it?

Thanks,

Stanley

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to send out emails before the reboot ?
Outbound traffic from port 25 is not allowed in GCP instances. Are you using a different port ?
Did you create a firewall rule in order to allow such traffic ?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail